# Inheritance mapping in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am having two sets of tables, inherited as follows:

```
Print
|
+-Magazine -+- ScientificMagazine
|           |
|           +- PopularMagazine
|
+-Book -+- EncyclopediaBook 
        |
        +- ReligiousBook
```

And the corresponding locale hierarchy:

```
PrintLocale
|
+-MagazineLocale -+- ScientificMagazineLocale
|                 |
|                 +- PopularMagazineLocale
|
+-BookLocale -+- EncyclopediaBookLocale
              |
              +- ReligiousBookLocale
```

I am trying to map the classes of Prints to the corresponding Locales.

Note that class Locale is an enum of {en, de, fr, es, cs} - abbreviations of languages.

So in the class of Print I have a EnumMap to map the corresponding Locales to the Print:

```
public class Print<T> {
    ...
    @ElementCollection
    @JoinTable (joinColumns = @JoinColumn (name="print_id"))
    @MapKeyColumn (name="locale")
    protected Map<Locale, T> locales = new EnumMap<Locale.class>();
    ...
```

My problems are:

1. When I try mapping inherited classes (for inst. Mapping ScientificMagazineLocale which inherit variables from its parents to ScientificMagazine), I am getting ArrayOutOfBoundException. If I copy all the contents of PrintLocale, MagazineLocale to ScientificMagazineLocale and remove the inheritance, everything works correctly.
2. As the PrintLocale is mapped in the Print class, hibernates always tries to generate "print_locales" table instead of corresponding tables (popular_magazine_locale, scientific_magazine_locale, ...), even though in PopularMagazineLocale I define @Table (name="popular_magazine_locale").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use @MappedSuperClass to the parent abstract classes.

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem:
@JoinTable( joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="print_id")})

Try that.

My guess is that Hibernate expects "joinColumns" to be an array. Which is why you would need to add these { } brackets.

As for your second problem,
JPA 2.0 states the default for @Inheritance is InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE. Which is used if no @Inheritance annotation is provided.
As a result - everything gets mapped to 1 table.